# Derby - How to handle additions to objective fields

Tags: java, derby, bit-fields

I'm looking to create a table for users and tracking their objectives. The objectives themselves would be on the order of 100s, if not 1000s, and would be maintained in their own table, but it wouldn't know who completed them - it would only define what objectives are available.

```
Objective:
ID  |  Name   |  Notes  |
----+---------+---------+
    |         |         |
```

Now, in the Java environment, the users will have a java.util.BitSet for the objectives. So I can go

```
/* in class User */
boolean hasCompletedObjective(int objectiveNum) {
    if(objectiveNum < 0 || objectivenum > objectives.length())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Objective " + objectiveNum + " is invalid. Use a constant from class Objective.");
    return objectives.get(objectivenum);
}
```

I know internally, the BitSet uses a long[] to do its storage. What would be the best way to represent this in my Derby database? I'd prefer to keep it in columns on the AppUser table if at all possible, because they really are elements of the user.

Derby does not support arrays (to my knowledge) and while I'm not sure the column limit, something seems wrong with having 1000 columns, espeically since I know I will **not** be querying the database with things like

```
SELECT *
FROM AppUser
WHERE AppUser.ObjectiveXYZ
```

What are my options, both for storing it, and marshaling it into the BitSet?
Are there viable alternatives to java.util.BitSet?
Is there a flaw in the general approach? I'm open to ideas!

Thanks!

*EDIT: If at all possible, I would like the ability to add more objectives with only a data modification, not a table modification. But again, I'm open to ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[puts on fake moustache]*

Store the bitset as a [BLOB](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefjdbc96386.html). Start by simply serializing it, then if you want more space-efficiency, trying pushing the results through a DeflaterOutputStream on their way to the database. For better space- and time- efficiency, try the bitmap compression method used in [FastBit](https://sdm.lbl.gov/fastbit/), which breaks the bitset into 31-bit chunks, then run-length encodes all-zero chunks, packing the literal and run chunks into 32-bit words along with a discriminator bit.

If you know you'll only look at the objective bitset while the ResultSet that brought it from the database is still open, write a new bitset class that wraps the Blob interface and implements get on top of getBytes. This avoids having to read the whole BLOB into memory to check a few specific bits, and at least avoids having to allocate a separate buffer for the bitset if you do want to look at all the values. Note that making this work with a compressed bitset will take substantial ingenuity.

Be aware that this approach gives you no referential integrity, and no ability to query on the user-objective relationship, little flexibility for different uses of the data in future, and is exactly the kind of thing that [Don Knuth warned you about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: Did you know you have the same name, rep, badges, and cute-little-pink-icon as the other guy who answered? If it wasn't for the facial hair I'd think you're the same guy!

Comment: Kidding aside, the lack of referential integrity is actually something I'm weighing heavily. I'm definitely a fan of explicit over implicit where it's practical. With regards to the second, the entire objective bitset would need to be loaded in to memory during the login phase. The options available to the user will be heavily dependent on objectives already completed.

Comment: Also, thank you for your persistence (get it? this is about databases... okay I won't quit my day job...) with helping me here. Many would simply storm out and say "well if you're not going to do it <way suggested> don't bother doing it at all!" or something as crazy.

Comment: @glowcoder: I'm playing the long game. If you implement this, then six months down the line, it'll bit you in the arse, and you'll turn around and say, "dang, that clean-shaven guy was right all along!".

Comment: @Tom aside from referential integrity (the objectives are clearly documented, so reforming their binding won't be too much of a concern) are there other serious issues that will get hungry in the proverbial six months?

Comment: @glowcoder: i can't point to any specific reasons, but this isn't something i know with my head, it's something i know with my gut.

Answer (score 1):

The orthodox way to do this does not involve bitsets at all. You have a table for users, a table for objectives, and a join table, indicating which objectives a user has. Something like:

```
create table users (
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null
);

create table objectives (
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null
);

create table user_objective (
    user_id integer not null references users,
    objective_id integer not null references objectives,
    primary key (user_id, objective_id)
);
```

Whenever a user has an objective, you put a row in the join table indicating the fact.

If you want to get the results into a bitset for a user, do an outer join of the user onto the objectives table via the join table, such that you get a row back for every objective, which has a single column with, say, a 1 for each joined objective, or 0 if there was no join.

The orthodox approach would also be to use a Set on the Java side, rather than a bitset. That maps very nicely onto the join table. Have you considered doing it this way?

If you're worried about memory consumption, a set will use about one pointer per objective a user actually has; the bitset will use a bit per possible objective. Most JVMs have 32-bit pointers (only old or huge-heaped 64-bit JVMs have 64-bit pointers), so if each user has on average less than 1/32nd of the possible objectives, the set will use less memory. There are some groovy data structures which will be able to store this information more compactly than either of those structures, but let's leave that to another question.

Comment: I am hoping to acquire all user data in a single query (not wanting to sound premature-optimization-ish, but a fast login is a requirement.) Since your proposed user_objective table grows vertically, would that make my single query hope impossible?

Comment: Yes. You'd need two queries, one for the information from users, one from user_objective.

Comment: I have a requirement that says all user data should be returned in a single query. In addition, the method described above would use an entire row to represent something that can and should be reduced to a single byte. The user_objective table would literally a hundred times more space than it should. (This assumes 32 bits for user_id, 32 bits for obj_id, and 32 bits for implicit row_id for a total of 96 bytes). I anticipate about 10000 users each with about 300 objectives. That should be roughly 3MB worth of data, not 288Mb. As objectives and users both grow, it simply won't scale.

Comment: That's not to say I don't like the approach - I do like how explicit it is, which would certainly ease the debugging/development process. But being two orders of magnitude less efficient for storage seems more than I'm willing to go with for now. I'm not one who likes to prematurely optimize, but I know this will not be scalable.

Comment: 288 MB is not a particularly large amount for a database; it's certainly an awful lot more than 3 MB, but there's no scalability problem there. Also, worrying about scalability and using Derby seems like an odd combination to me!

Comment: That is a good point about Derby and scalability. I'm using Derby for this stage, and I plan simple, standard SQL paradigms such that it can be ported to MySQL or Oracle in the pre-production stage.